# an error in truffle test with "It" statement

Tags: error-handling, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am using a course, from udemy, it is called "The Complete NFT Web Development Course - Zero To Expert" and I got an error, at 174, I am making a smart contract, called 'Kryptobird.js' and got an error.
if theres anything wrong with the code, please help me

```
const assert = require('chai')

const KryptoBird = artifacts.require('./KryptoBird')

// check for chai
require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()
contract('KryptoBird', (accounts) => {
let contract


describe('deployment', async() => {
    It('deploys successfuly', async() => {
        contract = await KryptoBird.deployed()
        const address = contract.address;
        assert.notEqual(address, '')
        assert.notEqual(address, null)
        assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
        assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
    })
}) 
})
```

and this is the error I'm getting when I run the command 'truffle test' :

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLyXG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- `It` should not be capital "I"

```
it("deploys successfully", async () => {
```

2- also this might cause error `artifacts.require('./KryptoBird')`

it should not be the relative path. it should be the name of the contract

```
const KryptoBird = artifacts.require("KryptoBird");
```

3-

```
 const { assert } = require("chai");
```

Comment: I did what you said, but It still gives me a similar error, but not the same.


 Contract: KryptoBird
    deployment
      1) deploys successfully
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (207ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: KryptoBird
       deployment
         deploys successfully:
     TypeError: assert.notEqual is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\KryptoBird.test.js:18:20)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: @Koruma const { assert } = require("chai");